# Operator norm of real matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

I've been looking through my workbook in preparation for the next set of classes and I'm stuck on this problem and don't know how to possibly proceed with it. The hint isn't helping and there isn't any answers.

Any help on this question would really be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For ${\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$\eqalignno{
\Vert A\,{\bf x}\Vert_1&=\sum_{i=1}^m\left\vert\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j\right\vert\cr
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^m\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2}\cdot\Vert {\bf x}\Vert_2&\hbox{by Cauchy-Schwarz}\cr
&\leq\Vert {\bf x}\Vert_2\sqrt{m}\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2}&\hbox{again by Cauchy-Schwarz}\cr
&=\sqrt{m}\Vert A\Vert_2 \Vert {\bf x}\Vert_2\cr
&\leq\sqrt{m}\Vert A\Vert_2 \Vert {\bf x}\Vert_1&(*)\cr
}
$$
and the desired result (i.e.  $\Vert A\Vert_1\leq\sqrt{m}\Vert A\Vert_2$,) follows. Note that the final step in (*) follows from the well-known inequality
$$
\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|
$$